# Type mismatch with Binding.scala involving scala.xml.Elem

Tags: sbt, scala.js, binding.scala

I'm failing to compile a simple example of **Binding.scala**, and being a newbie, I have no intuition how to fix it. Maybe the README is slightly outdated? The example at https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala-sample is even older and causes deprecation warnings.

My code, which I basically stuck together from the README, and even simplified a bit:

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding.dom
import org.scalajs.dom.document
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport

@JSExport
object SampleMain {

  @dom
  def table = {
    <table border="1" cellPadding="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  }

  @JSExport
  def main(): Unit = {
    dom.render(document.body, table)
  }

}
```

`fastOptJS` causes a compile error:

```
SampleMain.scala:25:9: overloaded method value render with alternatives:
[error]   (parent: org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node,children: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.BindingSeq[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node]],dummy: Unit)Unit <and>
[error]   (parent: org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node,children: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.BindingSeq[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node])Unit <and>
[error]   (parent: org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node,child: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node])Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLElement, scala.xml.Elem)
[error]     dom.render(document.body, table)
[error]         ^
```

I suspected a problem with type inference and tried this type annotation: `def table: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[org.scalajs.dom.html.Table]` but this caused another error:

```
SampleMain.scala:11:6: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.xml.Elem
[error]  required: com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[org.scalajs.dom.html.Table]
[error]     (which expands to)  com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding[org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLTableElement]
[error]     <table border="1" cellPadding="5">
[error]      ^
```

I'd appreciate an explanation what is going wrong here.

---

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55137909/1862339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the `paradise` compiler plugin was not picked up in my case. I'm building an SBT multi-project with Binding.scala in a sub-project only, and `addCompilerPlugin` does not propagate to sub-projects. To make it work, it needs to be added to the sub-project's settings like this:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("client"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.thoughtworks.binding" %%% "dom" % "11.6.0"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
  )
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
```

Before I had `addCompilerPlugin` at the top-level of `build.sbt`, which did not work and caused the compile error.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have added this to your `build.sbt`

```scala
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

The main macro of `Binding.scala` (which translates Scala XML literals into special `Binding` types) does not work without this plugin and the compiler sees only the original types (`scala.xml.Elem`).

This is mentioned in the `Step 1` of the README.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me into the right direction! My build was a bit more complicated and I did (try to) configure the compiler plugin, but it was not correct (see my own answer). Your insight really helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an error message, which asks you to enable the `paradise` compiler plug-in. Unfortunately because you are using Scala 2.10, [a bug in `macro-compat`](https://github.com/milessabin/macro-compat/pull/61) prevent you to see the error message.

So the long answer is:

1. Upgrade Scala to 2.11 or 2.12, by setting something like `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.8"` in your `build.sbt`.
2. You will see an error message that asks you to add the `paradise` plug-in.
3. Finally, add the following setting in your `build.sbt` according to the error message:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Comment: Actually I was using Scala 2.12 but did not see the helpful error message. Maybe because I am using an SBT multi-project build? Anyways, the compiler plugin was the hint I needed, I fixed a misconfiguration in SBT (see my answer). Thanks!